# Do office.js custom contextmenu items show up in Word 2016 on iPad? What about custom Ribbon buttons?

Tags: office-js

I have sideloaded my basic Word add-in to an iPad and it works...but the user experience is not good because everything depends on a taskpane, which shrinks the size of the document too much.

I'm beginning to experiment with context menus and also adding custom buttons to an existing Word ribbon (vs. my custom ribbon).

Does office.js for iOS/iPad currently support either of these?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are not currently supported on iOS/iPad according to [Add-in Commands](https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/design/add-in-commands). Scroll down to the Supported Platforms section.

Comment: Thanks Rick...apparently iOS Outlook has the ability to add a button...but no capabilities for other Office apps on iOS.